# Can't convert string into number

Tags: javascript

I have a large text from which I read data according to the scheme. Key words are placed in the "smallArtName" array. The scheme looks like this:

> (key word) xxx (cordX|cordY)

I can't convert the string I received to a number. It seems to me that the reason is white space, visible in the terminal in the picture. I tried to use the replace method which works for sample text, but not for my value.

I'm a beginner and I could probably do it simpler, but the code I wrote works, and this is the most important thing for now.

```
for (i = 0; i < smallArtName.length; i++) {
   var n = art.artPrintScreen.indexOf(smallArtName[i]);
   if (n > -1) {
    var tempString = art.artPrintScreen.substring(n, n + 100);
    betweenChar = tempString.indexOf('|');
    for (k = betweenChar - 10; k <= betweenChar + 10; k++) {
     if (tempString[k] == '(') {
      xStart = k;
     }
     if (tempString[k] == ')') {
      yEnd = k;
     }
    }
    cordX = tempString.slice(xStart + 1, betweenChar);
    cordY = tempString.slice(betweenChar + 1, yEnd);

    strTest = "  t est".replace(/\s/g, '')
    var cordY2 = cordY.replace(/\s/g, '')

    console.log(typeof (cordY))
    console.log(cordY2)
    console.log(cordY2[0])
    console.log(cordY2[1])
    console.log(cordY2[2])
    console.log(cordY2[3])
    console.log(cordY2[4])
    console.log(cordY2[5])

    console.log(strTest)

    var cordYtest = parseInt(cordY2, 10);
    console.log(cordYtest)
   }
  }
```

Terminal:

```
-181

-

1
8
1
test
NaN
string
-154

-

1
5
4
test
NaN
string
104

1
0
4

undefined
test
NaN
```

Fragment of input text:

```
Ukryta twierdza (Mapa podziemi I)       153 ‭(‭−‭72‬‬|‭−‭155‬‬)‬
Ukryta twierdza (Amfora Mgły VI)        135 ‭(‭73‬|‭104‬)‬
Ukryta twierdza (Mapa podziemi IV)      131 ‭(‭154‬|‭−‭72‬‬)‬
```

Comment: Can you show some lines of the input string?

Comment: added at the end of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing your sample input strings, I found some unicode characters [`\u202c`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm) and [`\u202d`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm) that should be stripped before converting to number. Also, the negative values are prefixed by the character `−`, which is different than minus `-`, se we need to replace it. That being said, all parsing could be done with a single regex:

```js
var input = "Ukryta twierdza (Mapa podziemi I)       153 ‭(‭−‭72‬‬|‭−‭155‬‬)‬";
input = input.replace(/\u202d|\u202c/g, "");
input = input.replace(/−/g, "-");
var m = input.match(/.*\((.*)\)\s*(.+?)\s*\((.+)\|(.+)\)/);
console.log(m);
console.log(parseInt(m[3]));
console.log(parseInt(m[4]));
```

Explaining the regex:

`.*` - Something that will be ignored

`\((.*)\)` - Something enclosed in parenthesis

`\s*(.+?)\s*` - Something possibly surrounded by spaces

`\((.+)\|(.+)\)` - Two parts split by a `|` and enclosed by parenthesis

Comment: Thank You! But still problem with negative value

Comment: Fixed now, `−` != `-` ;)